# Override Action with Component in Lightning Console as overlay or modal instead of a new tab

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, aura, console, component

From a list view, either by overriding a standard action or by using a list button, I would like to open my lightning (currently using aura) component in a modal dialog *instead* of a new tab in the console.

Any idea how to achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is support for this right now in Salesforce. The closest thing I could think of is use the "Display in existing window without sidebar or header" and make the content source a Visualforce page. You can then embed your aura component into the Visualforce page.

Certainly wouldn't be the standard lightning look and feel but it should get the job done. Here is more information on embedding lightning components in a Visualforce page.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm